# Merge in external changes made while editing

Tags: merge

If there are external changes made to a file being edited in Vim I understand that I can reload the content of the file by [`:edit`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/149209/refresh-changed-content-of-file-opened-in-vim/149214). But, assume that (internally) I've made changes to the file that I want to preserve. Is there a way to integrate the two sets of changes (external and internal)? From what I understand, `:edit` simply takes the external changes.

Comment: Have to read [`:h autoread`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27autoread%27)? Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: `:autoread` reads in the external changes but in the event that changes are made to the file that is being automatically read, vim will notify me that there have been changes made externally to the file since I have made my internal edits. I am looking for a way to merge the external changes with the internal ones.

Comment: Are you looking for `:h :DiffOrig`?

Comment: @ChristianBrabandt, it's never too late, right? This was a great answer. I didn't know that this existed.

Answer (score 3):

To elaborate on the [Christian Brabandt](https://vi.stackexchange.com/users/71/christian-brabandt)'s comment, here is a decomposition of the `DiffOrig` command:

Full command:

```
command DiffOrig vert new | set bt=nofile | r # | 0d_ | diffthis
    \ | wincmd p | diffthis
```

Decomposition:

```
command DiffOrig        " create a new command named DiffOrig
vert new                " open a new buffer splitted vertically
| set bt=nofile         " set buffer type to scratch 
| r #                   " read the alternate buffer (opened file to diff)
| 0d_                   " delete the first line
| diffthis              " diff the current buffer
| wincmd p              " move cursor to opened file 
| diffthis              " diff the current buffer
```

An alternate version use the `++edit` option for the read, it keeps the options values as if editing a file.

References:

- [`:h vert`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#vert)
- [`:h 'bt'`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27bt%27)
- [`:h read`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/insert.html#read)
- [`:h ++edit`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/editing.html#++edit)
- [`:h diffthis`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/diff.html#diffthis)
- [`:h wincmd`](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/windows.html#wincmd)